# Cannot pass enum value in CommandArgument for WebForms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, enums, webforms

In the CodeBehind class I have this:

```
Public Class MyControl
    Inherits UserControl

    ' Is used in other functions so cannot be hardcoded:
    Public Enum TabID
        Accepted = 138
        Declined = 139
        Unknown = 140
        InProgress = 141
    End Enum

    Public Sub Tab_OnClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim selectedTabID As Integer
        Dim linkBtn As LinkButton

        If Page.IsPostBack Then

            linkBtn = CType(sender, LinkButton)
            selectedTabID = CType(linkBtn.CommandArgument, Integer)

            ' Do stuff with selectedTabID...

        End If

    End Sub

    ' More irrelevant code...

End Class
```

And on the ascx file (code in front?) I have this:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="AcceptedTab" Runat="server" Text="Accepted" CssClass="selected"
    CommandArgument="<%# TabID.Accepted %>" OnClick="Tab_OnClick"/>
```

The problem is that the line `selectedTabID = CType(linkBtn.CommandArgument, Integer)` shows that `linkBtn.CommandArgument` is an empty string during debugging (should be "138") and it fails to convert the empty string to an integer during runtime.

I have also tried first converting the enum to an integer in the ascx file:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="AcceptedTab" Runat="server" Text="Accepted" CssClass="selected"
    CommandArgument="<%# CInt(TabID.Accepted) %>" OnClick="Tab_OnClick"/>
```

How can I get this enum value in the Tab_OnClick function using this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `DataBind()` on Page Load since you are binding data to a LinkButton with `<%#`.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)        
    DataBind
End Sub
```

Second, switch to `Command`, not `Click`. Then you have direct access to the CommandArgument

```
<asp:LinkButton id="AcceptedTab" Runat="server" Text="Accepted" CssClass="selected"
   CommandArgument="<%# CInt(TabID.Accepted) %>" OnCommand="AcceptedTab_Command"/>
```

And in code behind.

```
Protected Sub AcceptedTab_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
    Dim arg As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Will `DataBind()` also affect other controls on the page, such as a GridView? If so, should I assign things like this their `DataSource` value first before calling `DataBind()`? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: "Binds a data source to the invoked server control and all its child controls", so I suppose it does. I'll test it now.

Comment: got it all working. It does work as expected. Thank you!